# Starting Cygwin in arbitrary directory?

Tags: windows, cygwin

Is it possible to set up Cygwin so that if I call Cygwin.bat from an arbitrary path using arbitrary Windows-native launching method (cmd.exe, Total Commander' command line), it will start bash prepared in that directory?

For example, if I run cmd.exe and do following (provided that Cygwin.bat is on my `PATH`):

```
C:\Users\Me>cd testdir

C:\Users\Me\testdir>dir /b
myfile1
myfile2

C:\Users\Me\testdir>Cygwin
```

Cygwin window opens and I'm just where I left off:

```
me@here /cygdrive/c/Users/Me/testdir
$ ls
myfile1*  myfile2*

me@here /cygdrive/c/Users/Me/testdir
```

As you can see, when I get Cygwin prompt, I'm already at `testdir`, not at `/home/me`.

(More typical scenario where I'm going to use this is running Cygwin from Total Commander's command line, but I guess it should work the same.)

How to achieve this?

Comment: 'This' is what? How do you want to run Cygwin exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to hack something together for you. Put this in a batch file in your path (I called mine `cygwin.bat`, and called it by entering `cygwin.bat`):

```
@echo off
set pth=%CD:~2,99%
set pth=%pth:\=/%
set drv=%CD:~0,1%
set "fullpath=/cygdrive/%drv%%pth%"
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i -c "cd ""%fullpath%""; exec /bin/bash"
```

Comment: Works like charm, thanks! :) Wasn't able to make a version for "Cygwin Terminal" (using mintty.exe), but since I did not specify which terminal emulator to use, I may keep it for a separate Q.

Answer (score 4):

This **simpler** `.bat` file (`.cmd` in my case) is **working fine** for me:

```
c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i -c "export CD='%CD%'; cd \"$CD\"; exec /bin/bash"
```

Tested working on:

- CMD.
- Total Commander.
- Remote SSH session.
- Start Menu --> Run (in this case it opens at `C:\Users\Me`).

Comment: No need for the export, just cd directly:
`c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i -c "cd \"%CD%\"; exec /bin/bash"`

Comment: I got this working using Windows Terminal too.  Great solution!